# Question involving index laws; find the value of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, real-numbers, exponentiation

Here is the following question, I am currently working on:

> $$x^x = 2^{2048}$$
> Find the value of $x$.

I decided to start by letting $x = 2^n$, where $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then I used index laws:

- ${2^n}^{(2^n)}=2^{2048}$
- $2^n = 2^{(2^{11-n})}$

Finally acquiring:

- $n=2^{11-n}$
- $n^{\frac{1}{11-n}} = 2$

That is where I have been able to get so far. Anyone has ideas to progress further from here?

Answer (score 1):

*Forewarning:* This solution is probably overkill and far from intended, especially considering the answer itself ($256$) is a power of $2$. This is simply the first approach that comes to mind when handling stuff involving $x^x$ or $xe^x$.

---

**Overkill Solution Using Lambert $W$:**

Abstract things a bit to the equation $x^x = a$; $2^{2048}$ is simply a red herring and we can handle that specific case later.

Then we know that

$$x^x = e^{\ln(x^x)} = e^{x \ln(x)} = a \implies x \ln(x) = \ln(a)$$

By a property of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), applying it to both sides yields

$$W(x \ln(x)) = \ln(x) = W(\ln(a))$$

and so, by a further property,

$$x = e^{W(\ln(a))} = \frac{\ln(a)}{W(\ln(a))}$$

For $a=2^{2048}$ this becomes

$$x = \frac{2048 \ln(2)}{W(2048 \ln(2))}$$

$W(2048 \ln(2))$ is hard to work with, but we note the property we used before, $W(x \ln(x)) = \ln(x)$. If we can somehow rebalance $2048 \ln(2)$ so that the same thing is outside and inside the logarithm, we're golden. Luckily, since $2048$ is a power of $2$ ($2^{11}$) this is easy: just reallocate one power of $2$ at a time back inside:

$$\begin{align*}
2048 \ln(2) 
&= 1024 \ln(4) \\
&= 512 \ln(16) \\
&= 256 \ln(256)
\end{align*}$$

Hence:

$$x = \frac{2048 \ln(2)}{\ln(256)} = \frac{2048 \ln(2)}{8 \ln(2)} = 256$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You properly arrived at the equation

$$n=2^{11-n}$$

Take logarithms
$$\log_2(n)=11-n \implies n+\log_2(n)=11\implies n <11$$  There is a very small range to explore.